# How to set up my analytics code in thankyou.php page to track the goal after form submission?

Tags: php, analytics, goal-tracking

`I am using an HTML site and on contact us form, I have kept a thankyou.php page after submission of the form. And already I have created a goal in the analytics and kept destination equals to the thankyou.php URL. But the thing is,  I am unable to track the goals of the analytics. And I tried to insert the analytics code in the thankYou pages.e, I embedded javascript in the PHP page. And i tried to fill the form and hit the submit button. but still, I am getting an error like Fatal error: Call to undefined function contents().
 Let me know How can i resolve this?
Thank you in advance for your answers :)

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-9XXXXXXXX-
1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-9XXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

I used to create a separate js file and inserted the code in that 
and then I embedded the js file in thankyou.php like this

```
<?php

   $script = file-get-contents('javascriptFile.js');
   echo "<script>".$script."</script>";

?>
```

But when i inserted and did a submission then im getting a fatal error

Comment: Post your code also

Comment: Try `file_get_contents` instead of `file-get-contents`. Also: "then im getting a fatal error" -> which one? what does the error message say?